# How to make different number of column in Flutter using Datatable or Table wigets?

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to create a table like this in Flutter.

[image]

When I try to do this using Datatable or Table widgets, it gives me an error. It says because the number of columns of each row in the table must be equal. I solved this problem by using a different table widget. For now, I created two tables and used a table widget, one with fewer columns and the other with the same number of columns.

```dart
Column(
      children: [
        Table(
          children: const [
            TableRow(children: [
              Text("Column Header"),
            ])
          ],
        ),
        Table(
          children: const [
            TableRow(children: [
              Text("Col1"),
              Text("Col2"),
              Text("Col3"),
              Text("Col4"),
            ]),
            TableRow(children: [
              Text("x1"),
              Text("x5"),
              Text("x9"),
              Text("x13"),
            ])
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )
```

But is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After doing some research on the internet, I found a library called ***Syncfusion***. I solved my problem with ***stacked headers*** provided by [this](https://www.syncfusion.com/flutter-widgets/flutter-datagrid) library.

It provides us like this table:

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not answer to the question just the promotion of some package.

Comment: This is the solution I found for my needs and it met my needs. If you have a better answer you can write it. But I think it's an adequate answer for now.

Comment: @MehmetKaragöz No it's not ! It's just a band-aid for your problem. You shouldn't use a package for every little thing.